# Python Django - How can I use different db for different apps and users?

Tags: python, django

I have the following situation:

1. One db storing users data - let's say for "auth" app
2. One common db for data common for all users - call it "common" db
3. While registering, each user should have new db created "user" db

In general there are two apps: auth and app2.

How can I create a new database and setup a connection while registering new user?

Comment: Why do you want to have a different database for each user? That's unusual.

Comment: You might already read the documentation, if not this might help you to get into the right direction. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/